# Using ArcGIS webmap offline?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, offline

I am working with a simple map application (basemap and some points/markers) that is using ArcGIS services. The map was developed about 2 years ago but this year (due to security measurements, firewalls etc) it is only accesible by a VM without internet connection (the web application is on an internal server).

Is there any way to run an ArcGIS application (using JS API) without any connection to Esri servers or should I look for the alternatives?

Leaflet looks promising but I would not want to re-engineer the whole application.

Comment: What services are you using from ESRI servers? Can you do without the Basemap? In that case just install the ESRI API on your server.

Comment: I have been trying to follow [this](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011974) but it tires to connect to js.arcgis anyway.
As for the basemap, I think that basemap is quite expected to be a part of service but I figured out that I could download the needed area from OSM.

Comment: Have you updated the API in your App? can you see which line is making a request to the online url?

Comment: It looks like there is some line from inint.js that wants to connect to js.arcgis.com. It could be as well that the API is outdated. Will check if using the old API will be helpfull (as it is easier from my experience to get the app up'n'runnin with old API and then upgrade)

Comment: Generally, the way to get the JSAPI to operate locally is to stand up an ArcGIS Server inside your firewall. This represents a significant cost. The JSAPI installation documentation explains how to alter the init file to access your local Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ArcGIS Javascript [can be downloaded from My Esri](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_accessapi.html).  This will also include instructions on how it can be installed on a local server.

Comment: As Simon mention, there is no problem tu use the API offline, I did it a couple of times. The unique problem is that you have to provide an "Offline Basemap", because you cannot consume the normal one from ArcGIS Online, due to you do not have internet access.

Comment: Sorry for late response. The basemap was in fact the problem. I went with hosting OSM data on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing ArcGIS Idea to [Provide an ArcGIS JavaScript API Offline Solution](https://community.esri.com/ideas/13210-provide-an-arcgis-javascript-api-offline-solution).

In a comment on that, [GitHub - Esri/offline-editor-js: ArcGIS JavaScript library for handling offline editing and tiling](https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js) is suggested:

> ArcGIS JavaScript library for handling offline editing and tiling.